# Cosmos db ARRAY_LENGTH performance

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I had a issue where a valid query didn't return anything while it should:

```
SELECT * 
FROM root 
WHERE 
    (ARRAY_LENGTH(root["orderData"]["_attachments"]) > 0
    AND root["orderData"]["_status"] = "ARCHIVEDVALIDATED") 
OR root["orderData"]["_status"] = "ARCHIVEDREJECTED"
```

Thanks to stackoverflow community, I found out that it was because it was taking too much RU and nothing would return.

After digging and trying serveral things, i found out that if I remove `ARRAY_LENGTH(root["orderData"]["_attachments"]) > 0`, my query goes from 13k RU to 600 RU..

I can't seem to find a way to fix this, the hotfix i found so far, is to remove the `ARRAY_LENGTH(root["orderData"]["_attachments"]) > 0` from the query and filter it later in memory (which is not good...)

Am I missing something? How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-length warns that the function doesn't use the index

Answer (score 3):

600RU is still very-very bad. That is not a solution.

The reason for such bad performance is that your query cannot use indexes and doing full scan can never scale. Being bad now, it will get worse as your collection grows.

What you need is make sure your query can use an index to only examine the smallest possible numbers of documents. Hard to propose exact solution without knowing your value data distribution on `orderdata.status` and `orderdata._attachments.length`, but you should consider:

- **Drop the OR**. Queries of "this or that" cannot use index. CosmosDB uses just 1 index per query. If  `orderdata.status` values are selective enough you would get
  a lot better RU/performance by doing 2 calls and merging results in client.
- **Precalculate your condition to a separate property and put an index on that**. Yes, that's duplicating data, but a few extra bytes cost you nothing, while RU and performance cost you a lot in money as well as in user experience.

You can combine them as well, for example by having 2 queries and storing the array count only. Think about your data and test it out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery has info on how to nest sql queries to do what this answer suggests, limit what the function operates on

Answer (score 1):

To figure out the discrepancy in RUs between the two queries, you may want to check the Query Metrics for both queries as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics.

You could also try to swap the first two expressions and see if this makes any difference. Basically try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM root WHERE (((root["orderData"]["_status"] = "ARCHIVEDVALIDATED") AND (ARRAY_LENGTH(root["orderData"]["_attachments"]) > 0)) OR (root["orderData"]["_status"] = "ARCHIVEDREJECTED"))
```

Comment: Changing the expressions didn't change anything. But trying to do the query metrics seems to show that it was only slow in the data explorer, and not inside the program.. not sure why...